# error trying to create two variables Cannot acquire a lock

Tags: arcpy, cursor, loop, error-999999

I am trying to create two variables one for x vertices and another for y vertices, when I leave the vertices as x, y the code runs but not when I separate the vertices into verticeX & verticeY

```
c_cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(out_shp)
for census in c_cursor:
    geo_census = census.Shape
    census_x = []
    census_y = []
    c_parts = geo_census.partCount
    for censusline in range(0, c_parts):
        parts = geo_census.getPart(censusline)
        for cord in parts:
            if cord:
                census_x.append(cord.X)
                census_y.append(cord.Y)
print 'step 1c'

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_shp, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]):
    print("Feature {}:".format(row[0]))
    partnum = 0
    for part in row[1]:
        print("Part {}:".format(partnum))
        for pnt in part:
            if pnt:
                verticeX= ("{}".format(pnt.X))
                verticeY= ("{}".format(pnt.Y))
                print verticeX, verticeY
            else:
                print("Interior Ring:")
        partnum += 1
print 'step 1c'
```

Here is my error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173\FPT.py", line 51, in <module>
    c_cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(out_shp)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1211, in UpdateCursor
return gp.updateCursor(dataset, where_clause, spatial_reference, fields, sort_fields)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 364, in updateCursor
self._gp.UpdateCursor(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Cannot acquire a lock.
Cannot acquire a lock.
```

update 1: Here is the line of code above. The code was running earlier then I added the verticeX= and verticeY= then the error message started appearing even when I converted it back to the format that worked.

```
fields = [
    ('NAME', 'TEXT'),
    ('STATE_NAME', 'TEXT'),
    ('CNTY_FIPS', 'FLOAT'),
    ('totpop', 'LONG'),
    ('Centroid_x', 'LONG'),
    ('Centroid_y', 'LONG')
]
print 'step1e'
for field in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(out_shp, "Centroid_X")
for field in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(out_shp, "Centroid_Y")
print 'step1f'
County_Name_List = []
State_Name_List = []
County_Fips_List = []
Tot_Pop_List = []
Centroid_List = []
print 'step1g'
```

Comment: your error is happening in the first line of your code snippet - `c_cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(out_shp)`.  What happens before that line?

Comment: Why are you using an `UpdateCursor`?  You don't appear to be updating anything.  If that's the case, try changing it to a `SearchCursor` instead, and the locks may not be an issue.

Comment: I thought I was using an `UpdateCursor` because I was updating the lists `census_x` and `census_y`

Comment: those are python lists, they're not part of `out_shp`, so all you're doing is getting values from `out_shp` and appending them to those lists.  You don't need an update cursor to append lists.

Comment: I've switched it to `SearchCursor` and it still gives me the same error as above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're tripping over your own feet here.. All cursors need to be removed or they will lock the data; until you free the cursor you could still go back to it at any stage.

In your code you're using a mixture of old and new style cursors, I wouldn't, try to stick to one or the other. They both work but I would use arcpy.da cursors exclusively. Older style cursors need to be released with the `del` statement but arcpy.da cursors are compatible with `with` statements:

```
# older style cursor, I would discourage you from doing it this way
# c_cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(out_shp)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_shp,["SHAPE@"]) as c_cursor:
    for census in c_cursor:
            geo_census = census[0]
            census_x = []
            census_y = []
            c_parts = geo_census.partCount
            for censusline in range(0, c_parts):
                    parts = geo_census.getPart(censusline)
                    for cord in parts:
                            if cord:
                                    census_x.append(cord.X)
                                    census_y.append(cord.Y)
print 'step 1c'
# if you do you need to free it up
# del c_cursor

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_shp, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]) as s_cursor:
    for row in s_cursor:
            print("Feature {}:".format(row[0]))
            partnum = 0
            for part in row[1]:
                    print("Part {}:".format(partnum))
                    for pnt in part:
                            if pnt:
                                    verticeX= ("{}".format(pnt.X))
                                    verticeY= ("{}".format(pnt.Y))
                                    print verticeX, verticeY
                            else:
                                    print("Interior Ring:")
                    partnum += 1
print 'step 1c'
```

The with block ensures the resources are released at the end of the block - just make sure you don't reference the cursor after the block because it isn't there any more.

Later on, at step 1f you're trying to add fields:

```
fields = [
    ('NAME', 'TEXT'),
    ('STATE_NAME', 'TEXT'),
    ('CNTY_FIPS', 'FLOAT'),
    ('totpop', 'LONG'),
    ('Centroid_x', 'LONG'),
    ('Centroid_y', 'LONG')
]
print 'step1e'
for field in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(out_shp, "Centroid_X")
for field in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(out_shp, "Centroid_Y")
print 'step1f'
```

This is not correct, you're trying to add a field called "Centroid_X" and "Centroid_Y" many times. I assume you're trying to add each field in the list which should be done this way:

```
fields = [
    ('NAME', 'TEXT'),
    ('STATE_NAME', 'TEXT'),
    ('CNTY_FIPS', 'FLOAT'),
    ('totpop', 'LONG'),
    ('Centroid_x', 'LONG'),
    ('Centroid_y', 'LONG')
]
for field in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(out_shp, field[0],field[1])
```

This will give STATE_NAME the default field length which depends on your feature class type.